# Retrieve info about a file in wordpress media library

Tags: wordpress

I'm outputting some files from the media section on a page (i'm using a plugin called related links to do this). I have access to the id of the file....I need to query wordpress based on this id to get the upload date and description.

How do I do this? Can't find info on this in codex

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this solution: http://www.emmanuelgeorjon.com/eg-attachments-1233/

Good luck! :)